# Background image not showing for layout-sw600dp

Tags: android, android-xml

I'm testing on two different tablet sizes (7 and 10in). Placed two identical xml files in each folder layout-sw600dp-land and layout-sw720dp-land. The reference to the background drawable in res/drawable/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="@drawable/image" >
   ...
```

The image shows fine on the 10in but the background is white for the 7in? What could be happening with the sw600dp layout that is causing the image not to show? The two xml files are identical.

Comment: Which 7 inch tablet are you using for testing?

Comment: May be a silly question, but the path to the image is defined correctly in the xml?

Comment: Yes, like I said; the background shows fine on the 10in tablet with the exact same xml, except it is in layout-sw720dp-land

Comment: Is it possible that the image is too large for the 7in and small enough for the 10in to fit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into an issue similar to this recently. I had to use Bitmap caching to solve it. The images I was using were too big for Android to render; therefore, they didn't render at all.

**[How to load large Bitmaps efficiently!](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)**

Answer (score -1):

This won't work well on pre-3.2 devices, because they don't recognize sw600dp as a size qualifier, so you still have to use the large qualifier as well. eg, you should have a file named res/layout-large/main.xml which is identical to res/layout-sw600dp/main.xml.

Comment: Its a Nexus 7 running 4.3

Comment: Use these folder--->>     layout-large for 7" tablet (works on emulator and nexus7)
layout-xlarge for 10" tablet (works on emulator and galaxytab10.1)

Comment: That isn't the problem as your solution is just to accommodate devices running 3.2 or lower